# How to get the coordinates of a 3d graph when I have two variables and a constant?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, graphics3d, projection

```
f[p_, q_, c_] := -p*Log2[p] -q*Log2[q] - (1 - p)*Log2[1 - p] - (1 - q)*Log2[1 - q] + (p*q + (1 - p)*(1 - q))*Log2[c] + (1 - p*q - (1 - p)*(1 - q))*Log2[1 - c]
```

This is my equation.

I wanted to plot this 3D graph. As a function of p and q. "c" is a constant here, which I vary and see what happens to this function. The code I have written is this.

```
flo = Manipulate[ Plot3D[{f[p, q, c]}, {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, ImageSize ->{400,400}], {c, 0.001, 1}]
```

I get the graph as shown in the picture. [image]

Essentially I want to get the values of p, q and c such that f[p,q,c]<1, how can I do that?  I thought of extracting the coordinates of the graph and use the get coordinates option, but I have mathematica 10.3. It doesnt seem to be working here.

What are my options now? How do I proceed?

Comment: Can you please format your post and place all code in code blocks? Otherwise, it cannot be copied and pasted back to Mathematica intact.

Comment: Done. I hope this is okay? New to Stack Exchange. Sorry!

Comment: `NMaximize[{f[p, q, c], 0 < p < 1 && 0 < q < 1 && 0 < c < 1}, {p, q, 
  c}] ` yields `{1., {p -> 0.5, q -> 0.5, c -> 0.5}} `  . This, together with the graphical interpretation indicates, that only the point {p,q,x} = {1/2,1/2,1/2} does not satisfiy the conditon f[p,q,x] < 1.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.